# Remote Access to Local ASP.NET Core app NGINX

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nginx, .net-core

I published my **ASP.NET Core** app on my **raspberrypi3** (raspbian) with **nginx**.

I configured nginx following the microsoft documentation: on localhost everything works correctly but I can't access the app from other devices on my local network (ERR_CONN_REFUSED).

I set the reverse proxy on port 81 because on port 80 I have another server that manages php sites (including phpmyadmin) like this:

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80;

root /var/www/html;

index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

server_name php.it *.php.it;

location / {

    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}


location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
}}
```

and

```
server {
listen 81;

server_name example.com *.example.com;

location / {
    proxy_pass         http://localhost:5000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}}
```

I don't know if the problem is in the configuration of the `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` file or in the asp.net Core application.
I think the problem is localhost, but I have no idea how to solve it.

Also, I'm not sure what I should put in server_sites, what does it refer to?
Thanks

Comment: `server_name`  is correct? Are you accessing it correctly like this `example.com:81`?

Comment: @M1K1O thanks for the answer, i think it's wrong. I mean, i don't know what i should write in `server_name` and how to set it. Actually if i search for `example.com:81` i get `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`. How should i set it?

Comment: If you have your domain and DNS set up correctly, add it there. If you want to access it just via IP, like `172.28.0.1:81`remove it.

Comment: @M1K1O Ok, I just wanted to access it via ip so I removed it. in localhost it works but from another device I still get `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`. If nginx configuration is not a problem then I think it is an application problem. Do I need to set something in program.cs to access the app outside of localhost?

Comment: It your app is available at `http://localhost:5000` then app is set up correctly.

Comment: @M1K1O If I search localhost:81 I am redirected to localhost:5001 correctly. 
But if I search on another device 192.168.1.10:81 this time I get ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR. Problem with the https certificate?

Comment: I don't see you setting any certificate, so it is definitley missing. Though access via `http` should work.

Comment: @M1K1O I think it works, but my application automatically redirects to https. in conclusion i think i have problems because i have not installed the certificate. now i try to install the certificate on my raspberry, i will update. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first config, you have set up domain `php.it` so your site should be accessible via `http://php.it/` if you had set up correct DNS.

But you have set up listening to `default_server` so it is accessible also without host.

In your second case, there is missing `default_server` so host ist mandatory. On `example.com:81` should be your page accessible, again if you had set up correct DNS.

Solutions:

- If you want to access website without domain, just pure IP, remove `server_name`.
- If you want to set up default server even for port 81, add `listen 81 default_server;`